# How can I use an object as a function and an object?

Tags: javascript, closures

Trying to create a "class" in JavaScript that can both have a function at the root of the class and other sub functions:

`Validate(word)` - returns true or false if the word is validated

`Validate.getRule()` - returns the rules used to validate the word.

Here is example code:

```
var Validate = function (word)
{
  this.rule = /^[a-m]$/;

  if (word)
  {
     return this.rule.test(word);
  }
  else
  {
     return {
        getRule   :   function()
           { return this.rule;}
            };
  }

}();
```

This works the first time if you call it with no arguments, but the second time I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Comment: How do you want to use this, syntactically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are calling the function directly, the `word` parameter is always undefined, `this` is the global scope (`window`), so the code does the same as:

```
var rule = /^[a-m]$/;
var Validate = {
  getRule: function() { return this.rule; }
};
```

If you want something to work as both a function and an object, declare the function and then add properties to it (as a function is actually an object):

```
var Validate = (function(){

  var rule = /^[a-m]$/;

  function validate(word) {
    return rule.test(word);
  }

  validate.getRule = function() { return rule; };

  return validate;

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have scope issues.

```
var Validate = function (word)
{
  var that = this;

  this.rule = /^[a-m]$/;
  if (word)
  {
     return this.rule.test(word);
  }
  else
  {
     return {
        getRule   :   function()
           { return that.rule;}
            };
  }

}();
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) I would add that this is not really a good way to structure code in regards to scalability and maintainability - but that might not be an issue (and I know it wasn't part of the question)...

Comment: Hm... `Validate("asfd")` gives `TypeError: Validate is not a function`